# Custom error page routing struts 2 + spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to run a struts 2 application in spring boot provided embedded tomcat, I have managed to do so following the link https://jgalacambra.wordpress.com/2016/06/13/spring-boot-and-struts-2/.  The application is working, however I am not able to get through the custom page error routing based on http error code which was configured earlier in web.xml. I have tried below solutions so far and none of them seems to work as  I keep getting default tomcat error page for 404.

Things I have tried so far:

1.Disabled white label error page using.

```
             "server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false"
```

2.created public/error folder in src/main/resouces and placed all html error code related html files there.

3.Also tried creating templates folder under src/main/resources and placed http error code files there.

4.I have  also configured my filterregistration bean with below setting.

```
                   registration.setDispatcherTypes(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
```

Can someone please help what needs to be done for the error routing to work???

Comment: This seems to be unrelated to Struts 2, because you're trying to implement this functionality in Spring Boot, yes?

Comment: @Dave Newton, no i haven't removed struts2, i just made changes to have the app run on spring boots embeddded tomcat server, rest of the features of struts2 are still being used